# Check String against list of characters and replace it dynamically - Regex

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I'm trying to find a solution for this matter.
I have list of characters that needs to be replaced with particular character that is mapped with the original character.

Ex : I have character map which hold the characters and it's replacement value.
Character Map :

```
Map<String, String> characterMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
characterMap.put("&", "\x26");
characterMap.put("^", "\x5e");
```

String that needs to be replaced : `String hello = "Hello& World^";`
I want replace hello string with the values in the map. This map is created from the property file and it is dynamic.

Can I achieve this by a regex ?
Can I achieve this without iterating the character map ?

Comment: `Pattern.compile(".").matcher(hello).replaceAll(m -> characterMap.getOrDefault(m.group(), m.group()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code:

```sh
Map<String, String> characterMap = new HashMap<>();
characterMap.put("&", "\\x26");
characterMap.put("^", "\\x5e");

String hello = "Hello& World^"; 

Pattern.compile("\\W").matcher(hello).replaceAll(
   m -> characterMap.getOrDefault(m.group(), m.group())
        .replaceAll("\\\\", "$0$0"));
```

**Output:**

```
"Hello\\x26 World\\x5e"
```

**Details:**

- In main regex we match `\\W` which will match any non-word
- We extract value of each matched non-word character from `characterMap` or if that key is not found we get same character back.
- We call `.replaceAll("\\\\", "$0$0")` on extracted value to get right escaping (assuming values are just using single escaping). `$0` is the complete string we match in regex here which is `\\\\` and by using `$0$0` we make it `\\\\\\\\`.

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/7d7CQk)

---

Another optimized way of doing this is to construct regex using keys of your map like this:

```sh
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(characterMap.keySet().stream()
   .map(s -> Pattern.quote(s)).collect(Collectors.joining("|")));

// then use it with . getOrDefault
p.matcher(hello).replaceAll(m -> 
   characterMap.get(m.group()).replaceAll("\\\\", "$0$0"));
// => "Hello\\x26 World\\x5e"
```

Comment: Could you please let me know the why do we have $0$0 part ?

Comment: I have added explanation in answer, also check code demo.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash must be escaped, resulting in two backslashes `\\`; both in a java string literal, and in a .properties file.

```
    Map<String, String> characterMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Linked = keep order of inserting.
    characterMap.put("&", "\\x26");
    characterMap.put("^", "\\x5e");
```

But you mentioned that the source were a file.

```
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("charmap");

    String hello = "Hello& World^";

    System.out.println("Replaced: " + mapReplace(hello, bundle));
```

charmap.properties:

```
\\ = xx
& = \\x26
^ = \\x5e
```

In order for the replacements not to be replaced it is best to replace character wise.

```
private String mapReplace(String s, ResourceBundle characterMap) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    return m.replaceAll(mr -> {
        String c = mr.group();
        if (characterMap.containsKey(c)) {
            c = m.quoteReplacement(characterMap.getString(c));
        }
        return c;
    });
}
```

The `Matcher#replaceAll` expects the replacement to be in regex style, backslash escaped again, dollar `$` too and such.
For that one can use `Matcher#quoteReplacement`.

Last but not least, if you only want `\x..` as replacement:

```
private String mapReplace(String s, String keys) {
    return Pattern.compile("[" + keys.replaceAll(".", "\\\\$0") + "]").matcher(s)
            .replaceAll(mr -> String.format("\\\\x%02x", (int)mr.group().charAt(0)));
}

hello = mapReplace(hello, "^&");
```

The `keys.replaceAll(".", "\\\\$0")` is needed to have the regex `[\^\&]` aka `"[\\^\\&]"` as `-`, `^` and others have special meaning in regex.

In general it would have been advisable to use `\uXXXX` instead of `\xXX`.

---

This task almost looks like an ASCII-to-EBCDIC conversion, seeing those two characters. That could be done differently.

Also you might be able to use URL encoding, `%26`/`%5e`, for which exists the URLEncoder.